# Why df is reporting huge size for external disk

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-usage, ext4

I have one external disk of 32GB attached and mounted. All the details are provided in below command.

```
# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0  32G  0 disk /storage/1

# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb         64Z   64Z   32G 100% /storage/1

# df
Filesystem                1K-blocks                 Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       73786976294837417744 73786976294804701208  32700152 100% /storage/1

# du -sh /storage/1
4.0K    /storage/1

# mount | grep /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb on /storage/1 type ext4 (ro,relatime,errors=continue,data=ordered)

# grep /dev/sdb /etc/fstab
/dev/sdb /storage/1 ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime 0 0

# findmnt
TARGET                                SOURCE      FSTYPE      OPTIONS
/                                     /dev/sda1   ext4        rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,stripe=32592,data=ordered
`-/storage/1                          /dev/sdb    ext4        ro,relatime,errors=continue,data=ordered
```

**ISSUE:**

If we look at the `df` output, it is showing really weird and huge size for this disk.
The disk is not at all used. `df` (under `Avail`) reports this as 32 GB which is the size of the disk
Also, `du` reports 4KB.

So, I am unable to understand what could have gone wrong here with the `df` output for this device.

One of the google searches suggested that formatting `/dev/sdb` instead of creating a partition and then formatting `/dev/sdb1` could be the problem. However, I have a quite a few servers where same is followed and none has this issue.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by @Stephen, It seems like the file system is not healthy:

```
# dumpe2fs /dev/sdb
dumpe2fs 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

The `dumpe2fs` fails on this. Also, I looked at `dmesg` and find it did log few errors for this disk:

```
[Tue Sep 21 15:52:28 2021] EXT4-fs error (device sdb): ext4_map_blocks:567: inode #2: block 9253: comm ls: lblock 0 mapped to illegal pblock 9253 (length 1)
[Tue Sep 21 15:52:28 2021] EXT4-fs error (device sdb) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5460: Corrupt filesystem
[Tue Sep 21 15:52:30 2021] EXT4-fs error (device sdb): ext4_map_blocks:567: inode #2: block 9253: comm ls: lblock 0 mapped to illegal pblock 9253 (length 1)
[Tue Sep 21 15:52:34 2021] EXT4-fs error (device sdb): ext4_map_blocks:567: inode #8: block 4227126: comm jbd2/sdb-8: lblock 54 mapped to illegal pblock 4227126 (length 1)
[Tue Sep 21 15:52:34 2021] jbd2_journal_bmap: journal block not found at offset 54 on sdb-8
[Tue Sep 21 15:52:34 2021] Aborting journal on device sdb-8.
[Tue Sep 21 15:53:41 2021] systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 33min 33.126422s random time.
[Tue Sep 21 15:53:41 2021] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 2h 35min 49.981791s random time.
[Tue Sep 21 15:53:55 2021] EXT4-fs error (device sdb): ext4_map_blocks:567: inode #2: block 9253: comm du: lblock 0 mapped to illegal pblock 9253 (length 1)
[Tue Sep 21 15:53:59 2021] EXT4-fs error (device sdb): ext4_map_blocks:567: inode #2: block 9253: comm ls: lblock 0 mapped to illegal pblock 9253 (length 1)
[Tue Sep 21 15:54:01 2021] EXT4-fs error (device sdb): ext4_map_blocks:567: inode #2: block 9253: comm du: lblock 0 mapped to illegal pblock 9253 (length 1)
[Tue Sep 21 16:18:49 2021] systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 38min 44.297529s random time.
[Tue Sep 21 16:18:49 2021] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 3h 34min 3.596906s random time.
[Wed Sep 22 17:03:22 2021] EXT4-fs (sdb): error count since last fsck: 7
[Wed Sep 29 02:50:32 2021] EXT4-fs (sdb): initial error at time 1632219748: ext4_map_blocks:567: inode 2: block 9253
[Wed Sep 29 02:50:32 2021] EXT4-fs (sdb): last error at time 1632219841: ext4_map_blocks:567: inode 2: block 9253
[Thu Sep 30 04:28:24 2021] EXT4-fs (sdb): error count since last fsck: 7
[Fri Oct  1 06:06:15 2021] EXT4-fs (sdb): initial error at time 1632219748: ext4_map_blocks:567: inode 2: block 9253
[Fri Oct  1 06:06:15 2021] EXT4-fs (sdb): last error at time 1632219841: ext4_map_blocks:567: inode 2: block 9253
[Fri Oct  1 13:11:23 2021] EXT4-fs error (device sdb): ext4_map_blocks:567: inode #2: block 9253: comm du: lblock 0 mapped to illegal pblock 9253 (length 1)
[Fri Oct  1 13:11:23 2021] EXT4-fs error (device sdb): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[Fri Oct  1 13:11:23 2021] EXT4-fs (sdb): Remounting filesystem read-only
[Fri Oct  1 13:17:35 2021] EXT4-fs error (device sdb): ext4_map_blocks:567: inode #2: block 9253: comm du: lblock 0 mapped to illegal pblock 9253 (length 1)
```

On this box (as seen above dmesg error):

```
# hostname -i && dmesg -T | grep 'inode 2: block 9253' | wc -l
10.53.242.33
18
```

So I look at 2 other similar servers from this cluster (we are running [Clickhouse DB](https://clickhouse.com/) on this cluster) where same issue is observed:

```
# hostname -i && dmesg -T | grep 'inode 2: block 9253' | wc -l
10.52.115.33
610

# hostname -i && dmesg -T | grep 'inode 2: block 9253' | wc -l
10.53.98.72
171
```

So I am wondering how all the 3 servers are complaining about the exact same inode and block while all have their own individual 32GB device connected.

I could disregard this issue saying my disk is bad on this box which is fair enough to conclude, however exact same error with same inode and block on other servers is bit confusing to me. Also, these 2 servers also fail to report on `dumpe2fs` with same "bad magic number" error.

Comment: Wow! 64 Zetabyte. Where can I get this?

Comment: I want one too :-)

Comment: What does `sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sdb | grep count` show? 73786976294837417744 is 2<sup>66</sup> which suggests that a size field is missing its value somewhere...

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt for your time, I "think" it is issue with the disk. I have updated the question per your inputs. I am unsure why other servers (where same issue observed) are also complaining about the exact same inode and block number.

Answer (score 1):

Your partition table is damaged. If you don't care about the data, umount the partition and repartition the disk. It's also possible it's physically damaged in which case you should probably get rid of it.

I'd do this:

```
umount /storage/1
cat /dev/zero > /dev/sdb
fdisk /dev/sdb (or any other tool, including parted, gparted, gdisk, etc.)
mkfs.[whatever] /dev/sdbX
```

Comment: There’s *no* partition table...